# How to use path with spaces in shell with $*

Tags: shell, cygwin

The following two .sh files are my code.

If I don't use $* everything works, but if I use $* it will prompt "./test2.sh:line 8: C: / Program: No such file or directory".

I use cygwin on windows to run test.sh file.

test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
UNITY_PATH="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2018.4.14f1/Editor/Unity.exe"
BUILD_ANDROID_RES=./test2.sh

${BUILD_ANDROID_RES} \
-UnityPath "${UNITY_PATH}" \
```

test2.sh with $*

```
#!/bin/sh
parse_arguments() {
    UNITY_PATH=$2
}

build_android_assetbundle() {
    echo "aaa ${UNITY_PATH}"
    "${UNITY_PATH}" abc
}

parse_arguments $*
build_android_assetbundle
```

test2.sh without $*

```
#!/bin/sh
build_android_assetbundle() {
    echo "aaa ${UNITY_PATH}"
    "${UNITY_PATH}" abc
}

UNITY_PATH=$2
build_android_assetbundle
```

I hope to be able to use $ *, who can solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Why not `"$@"` but `$*`???

Comment: further reading ...  https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF

Comment: @oguzismail "$@" work for me ! Thank you!

Comment: @matzeri "$@" work for me ! Thank you!